# Can I cast the current instance to a Generic Type in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign the current instance of a class to a Generic Type (as shown in my code). The issue is that I'm not sure how to cast the current instance into the Generic type...

```
namespace Sample
{
   public partial class BaseCollectionForm<T1, T2> : BaseForm
   {
      private static T1 instance = default(T1);

      public static T1 GetInstance()
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode != System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Instance does not exist.");
            }
            else
            {
               instance = (T1)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T1));
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }

      protected BaseCollectionForm()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         if (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode != System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
         {
            if (instance != null)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Instance already exists");
            }
         }

         // This is the problem area... T1 will be the type of the SubClass that Inherits from this BaseCollectionForm class.
         // I need to assign the instance variable with this, but the this value of the subclass.
         instance = (T1)(this);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `BaseCollectionForm` has two generic type parameters `T1, T2`, how do you think that's possible to perform a such cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your declaration to:

```
public partial class BaseCollectionForm<T1, T2> : BaseForm where T1 : BaseCollectionForm<T1, T2>
```

Essentially, this says in C# what you've said in English as '*T1 will be the type of the SubClass that Inherits from this BaseCollectionForm class*'

Comment: For the example I provided, I removed this... but the class Inherits from another class called BaseForm. The line looks like this

public partial class BaseCollectionForm<T1, T2> where T1 : BaseCollectionForm<T1, T2> : BaseForm (which causes an error).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!